# Group radio buttons inside a datatable - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create webpage having table with radio buttons in primefaces using datatable component like below.

[image]

I found one solution to implement custom component as mentioned in http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077687/enterprise-java/group-radio-buttons-inside-a-jsf-datatable-component.html for JSF.

But it is time taking and a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces provides the custom layout for selectOneRadio. I implemented the table using the custom layout example of selectOneRadio as below. In this first column has width zero which contains the radio button.

```
<p:dataTable id ="employeeTable" rowIndexVar="rowId" var ="emp" value ="#{employeeList.employeeData}" widgetvar ="employeeTable" resizableColumns="true">

   <p:column headerText="" style="width:0px;">
     <p:selectOneRadio id="action" value="#{emp.status}" layout ="custom">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Amendment" itemValue="Amendment" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="KIV" itemValue="KIV" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Personnel No">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.perNum}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Empl Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" />
    </p:column>                             
    <p:column headerText="Yes">
        <p:radioButton  for="action" itemIndex="0" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="No">
        <p:radioButton  for="action" itemIndex="1" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Amendment">
        <p:radioButton for="action" itemIndex="2" />
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="KIV">
        <p:radioButton  for="action" itemIndex="3" />
    </p:column> 
</datatable>
```

Comment: this approach is not working for me with same syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use `p:selectOneRadio` outside of your dataTable with `layout` attribute set to "custom". Fill this radio with `f:selectItems` same as data provided to dataTable via "value" parameter.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" 
                  value="#{beanMB.selectedItem}"
                  layout="custom">
    <f:selectItems value="#{beanMB.tableItems}"
                   var="item"
                   itemValue="#{item.radioValue}"
                   itemLabel="#{item.radioLabel}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

In dataTable column use `p:radioButton` with `itemIndex` matching current `rowIndex`.

```
<p:dataTable var="item"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
             value="#{beanMB.tableItems}">

    <p:column headerText="Choice">
        <p:radioButton for="@form:customRadio" 
                       itemIndex="#{rowIndex}"
                       rendered="#{item.radioRendered}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```